# How do I make this function work for holding the mouse key down?

Tags: javascript, events, html5-canvas, mouseevent

I'm trying to make my mouse color multiple cells black in a big square grid as I hold it down and move the mouse across different cells but my function only seems to make the first cell black and then stop. As long as I hold the mouse button down, shouldn't it keep going? Sorry if this is a dumb question... Thank you very much to anyone who can give me some insight.

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", makeWall, false);

function makeWall(e) {
    var mouseX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft + window.scrollX;
    var mouseY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop + window.scrollY;
    if (mouseX >= 0 && mouseX <= canvas.width && mouseY >= 0 && mouseY <= canvas.height) {
        var arrayC = Math.floor((mouseX - cellOffsetLeft)/ (cellWidth + cellPadding));
        var arrayR = Math.floor((mouseY - cellOffsetTop)/ (cellHeight + cellPadding));        //all code above this just makes sure the x,y coordinates of where I'm clicking are correctly registered
        changeCellColor(cells[arrayC][arrayR], black);       //changes cell color to black for the first cell clicked on
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `mousedown` event is fired when the mouse button is pressed, *not* when the mouse is moved. Have you looked into using the `mousemove` event, with a flag (set/reset from `mousedown`/`mouseup`) to indicate whether the button is currently pressed?

Comment: Oh wow, that's a bit of an oversight on my part. That would definitely explain things. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out some code that suits my need. Thanks to nnnnnn above for sending me in the right direction. Here's the code:

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", makeWall, false);
document.addEventListener("mouseup", endWall, false);


function makeWall(e) {
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", moveMouse, false);
}

function moveMouse (e) {
    var mouseX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft + window.scrollX;
    var mouseY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop + window.scrollY;
    if (mouseX >= 0 && mouseX <= canvas.width && mouseY >= 0 && mouseY <= canvas.height) {
        var arrayC = Math.floor((mouseX - cellOffsetLeft)/ (cellWidth + cellPadding));
        var arrayR = Math.floor((mouseY - cellOffsetTop)/ (cellHeight + cellPadding));
        changeCellColor(cells[arrayC][arrayR], black);
        }
}


function endWall(e) {
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove", moveMouse, false);
}
```